# Restricting user to a single db in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I've a PostgreSQL Server with 5 db and 2 users: postgres and forge, both with Superuser attribute.

I want to create a third user that can only see and use one and just one of the db and by using it I mean only perform select.
I've tried different solutions but seems that the brand new user can access to all the other dbs.

Thank you

Comment: I've created a user with `CREATE USER newuser WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'newpassword'` then `GRANT connect ON DATABASE database_name TO newuser` then `GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SHEMA public TO newuser`